# Highcharts - Providing different range value in positive and negative side for Y-axis

Tags: highcharts

I am Planning to set different range value for positive and negative side.

[Fiddle Code] jsfiddle.net/hari41980/N9vfb/5/

The problem is as of with the data values we have no issues. But when the data value is changed to a higher value say 100000 the negative side range too starts as such of positive side. both sides start with 20k / -20k. need to control this

Is there anyway to control the y-axis tick range to maximum of the value on both sides.

Tried few options lying in the code.

Comment: This question is not very clear. What do expect to occur?

Comment: Scale range values to be different for negative side and positive side, and the values to be picked from data provided for min and max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set different scale for negative and positive sides. You can set `xAxis.min` and `startOnTick: false`.

To add some ticks (they will close to each others anyway!) you can create `tickPositioner` and return all ticks (negative and positive).

Comment: Tried those but in vain :-(( Any other suggestions